# ASP.Net stream images continuously to browser so that it looks like video

Tags: jquery, asp.net, streaming, signalr

Given a bunch of JPG images in memory, how would I stream it continuously to a web page so that it looks like a video ?

I am building a remote desktop feature for a windows forms app. It will take screen shots and post to a ASP.Net web site. On the ASP.Net side, I would receive the JPG images and put it in some queue. What is the best way to deliver to the browser ? set the response type to JPG & stream continuously - is this possible ? May be SignalR ?

Comment: I don't think signalr is the right tool for this, maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016894/it-is-possible-to-stream-video-with-signalr

Comment: also check this http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/48/Peer-to-Peer-Media-Streaming-with-WebRTC-and-SignalR.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this with SignalR. See it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2014/04/24/video-streaming-with-asp-net-signalr-and-html5.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an easy way.

On the html side, when the image loads, use the onload event to reload the image.

On the server side, using Monitor if the image is empty, wait for it. If not, then return the image and blank the variable.