# Streaming (live-) video from Server to Client using .NET Core Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, video-streaming, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to build a video-streaming application using `.NET Core Blazor`. A simple usecase would be to implement a live-webcam into a website. So far my solution is based on OpenCV's video capture (`OpenCvSharp4.Windows 4.3`) and an async method that constantly re-renders the image source converting it into a `Base64 string`. It is importat, that the video is coming from the server. Using `openCV` is optional. This is my Component:

```
@page "/webcam"

@using OpenCvSharp

<div class="top-row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="CaptureWebCam">Capture</button>
</div>

<img src="@_imgSrc" />

@code {
    private string _imgSrc;

    // Start task for video capture
    protected async Task CaptureWebCam()
    {
        // 0 = default cam (mostly webcam)
        using (var capture = new VideoCapture(0))
        {
            // set every image in videocapture as image source
            using (var image = new Mat())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    capture.Read(image);

                    // encode image with chosen encoding format
                    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.ToBytes());
                    _imgSrc = $"data:image/png;base64,{base64}";

                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    StateHasChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem is:**

Using a `base64` string for every image is not at all performant! From what I researched I should convert my raw video to an mp4 container (using `ffmpeg` for example) and then stream to an html `<video>` element using the `HLS` or `RTSP` protocoll: [DIY: Video Streaming Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228035/diy-video-streaming-server)

This is where I am stuck, because I can't seem to find a good framwework/library/api to stream mp4 to a website using `.net core blazor`. Any suggestions?

I found something like `VLC` and `WebRTC` but I am not sure this will work. Also I found out that streaming over `SignalR` in combination with `WebRTC` could work: [it is possible to stream video with SignalR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016894/it-is-possible-to-stream-video-with-signalr/63189564#63189564)

Comment: Little old this now, but you need a player thats capable of playing HLS on the client side. The normal HTML5 tag doesnt support it (afaik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used a stream in MJPEG format and <img> tag. Give out the stream via ApiController where a stream of jpeg frames is created. Worked video 800x600 30 FPS in the local network.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CameraController : ControllerBase, IDisposable
    {
...
        [HttpGet("{id}/[action]")]
        public async Task<FileStreamResult> Live(string id, string channel)
        {
            _stream = new SmartMjpegStream(channel);
            _cameras.Add(Id = id, this);
            return await Task.FromResult(new FileStreamResult(_stream, SmartMjpegStream.ContentType));
        }
...
    }
```

and next in *CameraView.razor*

```
<img src="camera/live?channel=rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.100/axis-media/media.amp" alt="..." />
```